# Looking for design pattern for flexibile generic serialization

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++17

I have a header-only library that provides three class (templates), namely

- an abstract `DAGNode`,

  ```cpp
  struct DAGNode;
  using NodePtr = std::shared_ptr<DAGNode>;

  class DAGNode 
  {
  public:
      virtual ~DAGNode(){}
      virtual std::string serialize() const = 0;

      auto const& get_parents() const {
          return m_parents;
      }
   protected:
      std::vector<NodePtr> m_parents;
  };
  ```
- non-abstract class template `impl::Derived<T>`, which is derived from `DAGNode` and which is not part of the libraries API and

  ```cpp
  // this needs to be specialized by consumer
  template <typename T>
  std::string serialize(T const&) {
      throw std::logic_error("Not implemented.");
  }

  namespace impl {

  // not part of the librarys API
  template <typename T>
  class Derived : public DAGNode 
  {
  public:
      Derived(T const& t) : m_value(t) {}

      std::string serialize() const override final
      {
          return ::serialize(m_value);
      }

      void add_parent(NodePtr const& ptr) {
          m_parents.push_back(ptr);
      }

  private:
      T m_value;
  };

  } // namespace impl
  ```
- class template `DerivedHolder<T>`, which stores a `std::shared_ptr<impl::Derived<T>>`, which is part of the libraries API.

  ```cpp
  template <typename T>
  class DerivedHolder
  {
  public:
      DerivedHolder(T const& t) : m_node(std::make_shared<impl::Derived<T>>(t)) {}
      NodePtr holder() const 
      {
          return m_node;
      }

      void add_parent(NodePtr const& p) {
          m_node->add_parent(p);
      }
  private:
      std::shared_ptr<impl::Derived<T>> m_node;
  };
  ```

In the current design, `DAGNode` has a virtual method `std::string serialize() const`. `Derived<T>` final overrides this method and delegates to the function template `template <typename T> std::string ::serialize`.

A consumer of this library will have to specialize the `::serialize` function template for whatever types it wants to use. A typical usage scenario is that the consumer will use the visitor pattern to iterate over all `DAGNode`s and call the virtual `serialize` method.

Here is a [minimal complete code example](https://godbolt.org/z/TM76TEsKn).

This approach works well, but I have now come across a use-case, where a consumer of this library needs to replace `template <typename T> ::serialize` with its own "magic implementation" along the lines of:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::string magic_serialize(T const& t) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, MyMagicClass> ) {
        return t.as_string();
    } else {
        MagicClass m(t);
        return m.as_string();
    }
}
```

Since `magic_serialize` is in no way more special than `::serialize`, specialization won't do the trick.

Therefore, we need to change the design pattern of the serialization framework of the header-only library. We are free to change any part of the library including the API, though I would prefer any minimally invasive solution over a complete rewrite. We are restricted to C++17 for now.

**How can I change the library in such a way, that the consumer has complete control over how any type is to be serialized?**

Comment: One technique is to pass the serialization policy as the additional template parameter: `template <typename T, typename Serializer = DefaultSerializer> class Derived {...}`. `DefaultSerializer` would then delegate to `::serialize` as before, so the specialization approach would continue to work. But the client could also pass a bespoke serializer. See e.g. [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) and its `Hash` parameter: the user can either specialize `std::hash` for their type, or pass their own hasher class.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yeah thnx that could work. In term of code changes this would mean I would have to replace all occurances of `Derived<T>` with `Derived<T,S>` and in consequence all instances of `DerivedHolder<T>` with `DerivedHolder<T,S>`. A similar solution would be to keep the `Derived<T>` class as is, but change the holder class to `template <typename T, typename NodeType=Derived<T>> DerivedHolder` and static_assert that `NodeType` is derived from `Derived<T>`. Then a consumer could subclass the node type and I would only have to add a template parameter to `DerivedHolder`, not `Derived`.

Comment: I wonder if there is a solution that doesn't require adding additioanl template parameters? Adding them is actually quite intrusive. But if it turns out that that's the only way so be it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Having thought about it for a bit, I will probably use your suggestion.

Comment: Obviously you can’t have two clients who each have control over the serialization for **all** types, so the closest you can have is a template parameter in the _base_ class that allows each client to create its own parallel class hierarchy that serializes with their own framework.